# Accessing custom HTTP headers using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers

I have a custom HTTP header called XOBSERVATORY-AUTH that is related to user login. I render a page:

```
req.headers['XOBSERVATORY-AUTH'] = token;
res.setHeader('XOBSERVATORY-AUTH',token);
res.status(200).header('XOBSERVATORY-AUTH',token).render('user_charging', {
   table: path.basename(__filename, '.js'),
   token: token, css: css, firstName: results[0].first_name
});
```

If the user chooses to logout I call the logout controller and use this:

```
const headers = req.headers;
```

For some reason, my custom header doesn't appear, only the default headers appear like host, accept etc. Can anyone tell me why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: appear where? --

Comment: when I use console.log. It doesn't exist in the headers const

Comment: I see. Request and response headers are separate buckets. You set a response header, but it looks like you are reading a request header.

Comment: I also tried to set the request header as you can see but still nothing

Comment: The server _probably_ shouldn't set request headers. Usually servers only set response headers. A client wouldn't be able to see a request header because the client is responsible for setting them.

Comment: So how would I make this work?

Comment: What is your end goal with this? It's not really clear.

Comment: I want to make a custom header that contains a token with a user's information when a user logs in and when the user logs out, validate that the user is logged in and then delete the token. I want to pass the token using a custom header

Comment: Headers only exist during a single request, so if you set a header during log in, that header is no longer reachable when logging out. The feature you are probably looking for is 'sessions'. Sessions use cookies to track and store information during multiple requests.